# markdown="1" not working inside the p tag

Tags: html, markdown

I'm using this line `<p id="article-content" markdown="1" >## Download tarball </p>` and I'm getting the actual same text as HTML.

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ww2C0.jpg)

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you using a particular markdown plugin to render your page? Markdown is not an HTML feature

Comment: Oh I see. No I thought it's an attribute. Well what plugin you will recommend? The API JSON markdown response has "\n" inside it. How am I suppose to tackle that?

Answer (score 3):

`markdown="1"` is a common, albeit non-standard, method to alter the behavior of a Markdown parser. Specifically, standard Markdown ignores Markdown syntax wrapped inside block-level HTML tags. With an appropriate extension enabled, adding `markdown="1"` as an attribute to the wrapping HTML tag will instruct the Markdown parser to not ignore Markdown syntax within the tag. However, you need to be using a Markdown implementation which includes support for the feature and enable the feature if it is not enabled by default.

For example, PHP Markdown Extra [documents](https://michelf.ca/projects/php-markdown/extra/#markdown-attr) the feature this way:

> Markdown Extra gives you a way to put Markdown-formatted text inside
>   any block-level tag. You do this by adding a `markdown` attribute to
>   the tag with the value `1` — which gives `markdown="1"` — like this:
>
> ```
> <div markdown="1">
> This is *true* markdown text.
> </div>
> ```
>
> The `markdown="1"` attribute will be stripped and `<div>`’s content
>   will be converted from Markdown to HTML. The end result will look like
>   this:
>
> ```
> <div>
>
> <p>This is <em>true</em> markdown text.</p>
>
> </div>
> ```

Note that the Markdown parser strips out the `markdown="1"` attribute as it is not a valid HTML attribute. It only has meaning for some "extended" Markdown parsers.

For completeness, the original Markdown rules [explain](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#html) that Markdown syntax is ignored when wrapped in HTML:

> Note that Markdown formatting syntax is not processed within
>   block-level HTML tags. E.g., you can’t use Markdown-style `*emphasis*`
>   inside an HTML block.

That being the case, the following Markdown:

```
<div>
This is *true* markdown text.
</div>
```

Would generate the following HTML when passed through a Markdown parser:

```
<div>
This is *true* markdown text.
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no `markdown` HTML attribute. Maybe you're working in some framework that is supposed to add that capability, and it's not working right?

Comment: Oh I see. No I thought it's an attribute. Well what plugin you will recommend? The API JSON markdown response has "\n" inside it. How am I suppose to tackle that?

Comment: That's a much bigger question: converting markdown to HTML is a nontrivial operation (as you can imagine). Googling around, I see at least one here: https://github.com/showdownjs/showdown but you'll have to see what works with the framework you're using.