# Inserting raw HTML into Markdown

Tags: markdown

I have a need for inserting raw HTML into a Markdown document, to be placed verbatim in the output; specifically I am trying to ensure that some parts of a document are encompassed in a container (e.g. `<div>`, `<aside>`, or `<section>`) without disrupting the formatting of the contents within.

However, if I do the obvious approach of:

```
<aside>

## My heading
Some text, some text, some more text.

</aside>
```

then the Markdown processor generates this invalid HTML:

```html
<p><aside></p>
<h2>My heading</h2>
<p>Some text, some text, some more text.</p>
<p></aside></p>
```

But if I try putting the added tags up against the text to be processed, e.g.

```
<aside>
## My heading
Some text, some text, some more text.
</aside>
```

then a few different things happen based on the actual contents being formatted, but none of them are correct — and the `<aside>` still gets wrapped in a `<p>` anyway.

If I use `<div>`, then all of the contents are rendered as plain text.

Is there a way to instruct the Markdown processor to treat a run of input text *literally*, with no processing whatsoever?

I am currently using Hoedown (via [Misaka](https://misaka.61924.nl)), which supports many modern Markdown extensions, but if there is a more modern Markdown engine which handles this better I will certainly consider switching to it.

Comment: @JohnHennig I'll change the title, although the one you suggest isn't an improvement IMO. Unfortunately I can't switch Markdown implementations, but do you have any examples of ones which don't behave this way?

Comment: A couple questions which are not strictly duplicates have answers which might be of help: [Grouping MarkDown elements in to DIV element or Custom html tag](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30668958/866026) and [markdown=“1” not working inside the p tag](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57121103/866026).

Comment: Also, `<aside>` is a new tag in HTML 5 which was not supported in older Markdown implementations as those implementations predate introduction of the tag. As Hoedown appears to have been abandoned 4-5 years ago, I suspect it never had support added for `<aside>` as a "block-level" tag. The behavior for `<div>` is as described in the two other questions I linked above.

Comment: @Waylan My overall request was more about being able to put raw HTML into a Markdown-based document without the Markdown processor deciding to wrap it in extraneous `<p>` tags. If this leads to a good reason to switch to a different Markdown processor then I will consider that as part of a solution, although it's less-than-ideal.

Comment: The raw HTML is wrapped in `<p>` tags because it is not recognized as "block level." As only known "block level" tags are not wrapped in `<p>` tags, an older implementation is not going to treat new HTML5 tags properly without updates.

Comment: @Waylan yes, I understand that (and that HTML5's new tags are newer than Hoedown), but `<div>` also fails (albeit in a different way, which is also not useful for my purposes). And my point is I'd like to just be able to tell the Markdown processor "hey, please insert this text verbatim," regardless of what types of elements are in it. If there's a common way of doing that in any Markdown editor, that would be great. If there's a Markdown editor that I should specifically switch to then that is something I will consider doing.

Comment: @Waylan Please understand that I actually do know what I'm doing, and I was just trying to find a simple solution to what seems like it *should* be a simple problem. I'm sorry if that didn't come across. But the problem here isn't my not understanding HTML or its versioning thereof. Perhaps the wording of my question was overly-specific to the particular tag I was trying to insert directly. My real question is simply, *how do I insert raw HTML without the Markdown processor altering it*

Comment: I am simply trying to explain the nuances of how Markdown handles raw HTML.

Comment: After considering your feedback, I think I understand your question better and have added a comprehensive answer. Hope I got it right.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The safe answer is to use the following:

```
<div class="aside">
<h2>My heading</h2>
<p>Some text, some text, some more text.</p>
</div>
```

However it is more complicated than that with many possible answers. Which answer applies to you depends on which Markdown implementation you are using as there are subtle differences between them. Let's start with the reference implementation (markdown.pl) and the [original rules](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#html), as that is what Hoedown claims to follow (see below).

### Old School Markdown

Many of the older parsers were first developed during the transition from HTML4 to XHTML1 and their behavior and handling of raw HTML reflect that. That said, some have been updated in more recent years to have support added for newer HTML features. However, the reference implementation has not been updated in over a decade and is a good starting place. Generally, if you can get something to work in the reference implementation, it will work in any implementation, so let's focus on that.

The rules start by describing the handling of block-level HTML tags, and then describe the span-level behavior as if it is the exception. However, in the code things work in reverse. The span-level behavior is the default and the block-level behavior is the special exception.

Naturally, when using span-level tags, you want the result to be wrapping a `<p>` tags. For example, `foo <i>bar</i> baz` should result in `<p>foo <i>bar</i> baz</p>`. So, to avoid having raw HTML wrapped in `<p>` tags, there are a very specific set of circumstances which the rules require:

> The only restrictions are that block-level HTML elements — e.g.
>   `<div>`, `<table>`, `<pre>`, `<p>`, etc. — must be separated from
>   surrounding content by blank lines, and the start and end tags of the
>   block should not be indented with tabs or spaces. Markdown is smart
>   enough not to add extra (unwanted) `<p>` tags around HTML block-level
>   tags.

There are 3 requirements there:

1. The block of raw HTML must start with a known block-level tag. As previously established, on older implementations, these tags must be valid block-level tags in the HTML4/XHTML1 specs. Anything recently introduced in HTML5 may not work consistently across implementations.
2. The opening tag must be preceded by a blank line or the beginning of the document and the closing tag must be followed by a blank line or the end of the document.
3. The opening tag must begin with the first character of the line. Any indentation will cause the parser to fail to recognize the block of text as block-level raw HTML.

Finally, the rules state:

> Note that Markdown formatting syntax is not processed within
>   block-level HTML tags. E.g., you can’t use Markdown-style `*emphasis*`
>   inside an HTML block.

Note that this differs from span-level HTML:

> Unlike block-level HTML tags, Markdown syntax is processed within
>   span-level tags.

That being the case, `<span>foo *bar*</span>` results in `<p><span>foo <em>bar</em></span></p>`, while `<div>foo *bar*<div>` results in `<div>foo *bar*</div>`. Note that in the first example, while the Markdown syntax (`*bar*`) was processed, the entire thing was wrapped in `<p>` tags. Conversely. in the second example, the Markdown syntax (`*bar*`) was not processed, but the block was not wrapped in `<p>` tags. Therefore, any content wrapped in block-level raw HTML must all be in raw HTML.

So, let's apply these rules to your example aside:

```
<div>
<aside>
<h2>My heading</h2>
<p>Some text, some text, some more text.</p>
</aside>
</div>
```

The `<div>` provides the tag which is recognized by older implementations. And the content is all raw HTML as it wouldn't get processed as Markdown anyway. [Babelmark](https://johnmacfarlane.net/babelmark2/?normalize=1&text=%3Cdiv%3E%0A%3Caside%3E%0A%3Ch2%3EMy+heading%3C%2Fh2%3E%0A%3Cp%3ESome+text%2C+some+text%2C+some+more+text.%3C%2Fp%3E%0A%3C%2Faside%3E%0A%3C%2Fdiv%3E) shows that this works on all implementations.

Of course, using both the `<aside>` and `<div>` tags is redundant, so you could simply use a `<div>` tag with an appropriate class assigned to it:

```
<div class="aside">
<h2>My heading</h2>
<p>Some text, some text, some more text.</p>
</div>
```

As Babelmark [shows](https://johnmacfarlane.net/babelmark2/?normalize=1&text=%3Cdiv+class%3D%22aside%22%3E%0A%3Ch2%3EMy+heading%3C%2Fh2%3E%0A%3Cp%3ESome+text%2C+some+text%2C+some+more+text.%3C%2Fp%3E%0A%3C%2Fdiv%3E%0A), that works everywhere as well.

If you are using an implementation which has added support for HTML5 block level tags, you could `<aside>` tag directly:

```
<aside>
<h2>My heading</h2>
<p>Some text, some text, some more text.</p>
</aside>
```

Of course, we still need to use all raw HTML. As Babelmark [demonstrates](https://johnmacfarlane.net/babelmark2/?normalize=1&text=%3Caside%3E%0A%3Ch2%3EMy+heading%3C%2Fh2%3E%0A%3Cp%3ESome+text%2C+some+text%2C+some+more+text.%3C%2Fp%3E%0A%3C%2Faside%3E%0A), this works on most, but not all implementations.

### Extended Markdown

Over the years many Markdown implementations have added non-standard extensions to the syntax which add additional functionality. For obvious reasons, many users would like to be able to have Markdown syntax processed within raw HTML blocks. Therefore, many years ago, PHP Markdown Extra [introduced](https://michelf.ca/projects/php-markdown/extra/#markdown-attr) the `markdown="1"` workaround which has been copied by many implementations. However, most implementations which support the extension need to have the extension explicitly enabled. It is not enabled by default.

If you are using an implementation which supports the extension, and the extension is enabled, then you could use this (if newer HTML5 tags are supported):

```
<aside markdown="1">
## My heading
Some text, some text, some more text.
</aside>
```

Or this (if HTML5 tags are not supported):

```
<div markdown="1">
<aside>
## My heading
Some text, some text, some more text.
</aside>
</div>
```

or...

```
<div class="aside" markdown="1">
## My heading
Some text, some text, some more text.
</div>
```

### Commonmark

Some people became frustrated with the inconsistencies across implementations and set out to define a strict specification which became known as Commonmark. However, the [Commonmark spec](https://spec.commonmark.org/0.29/#html-blocks), by its own admission, breaks some of the very clearly defined rules of the original implementation. Ironically, this only added more inconsistencies. One of the worst offenders is the raw HTML handling.

So long as your raw HTML block does not contain any blank lines, Commonmark will handle your block in the same manner as the old-school Markdown implementations. However, once you introduce a blank line, anything which follows that blank line will be parsed as Markdown.

Additionally, the Commonmark spec clearly defines a complete list of which tags are considered block-level tags. As it happens, `<aside>` is on the list of tags.

Therefore, if you are using a compliant Commonmark implementation, the following would work:

```
<aside>

## My heading
Some text, some text, some more text.

</aside>
```

Notice that the `<aside>` tag is immediately followed by a blank line, which instructs the parser to treat any content of the tag which follows as Markdown. As Babelmark [demonstrates](https://johnmacfarlane.net/babelmark2/?normalize=1&text=%3Caside%3E%0A%0A%23%23+My+heading%0ASome+text%2C+some+text%2C+some+more+text.%0A%0A%3C%2Faside%3E%0A), this works on Commonmark implementations, but not old-school implementations.

### Hoedown

Hoedown specifically [claims](https://github.com/hoedown/hoedown#features) to be "Fully standards compliant" with "the official Markdown v1.0.0 and v1.0.3 test suites." Note that these are the test suites for the old-school reference implementation, not the newer Commonmark spec. That being the case, we can assume the Commonmark trick for processing Markdown within raw HTML blocks will not work. Of course, you can certainly try it to be sure.

Hoedown also claims to have "optional support for several (unofficial) Markdown extensions." However, there is no comprehensive list of available extensions, nor is there any instructions on how to enable them. I don't have the tool installed, but perhaps there are instructions available from the command line? If you can find a way to enable a `markdown="1"` extension, then you can use that trick to get Markdown processing in your raw HTML blocks.

However, without any clear documentation otherwise, I assume Hoedown is an old-school implementation. I also noticed that the [html_block_names.gperf](https://github.com/hoedown/hoedown/blob/master/html_block_names.gperf) file in the repo does not list `aside` as a known HTML block-level tag. Therefore, we can assume any raw HTML blocks must be wrapped in one of the 24 tags listed in that file.

Given the above, we can safely assume that the following is the only sure way to get the desired results from Hoedown:

```
<div>
<aside>
<h2>My heading</h2>
<p>Some text, some text, some more text.</p>
</aside>
</div>
```

or...

```
<div class="aside">
<h2>My heading</h2>
<p>Some text, some text, some more text.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the incredibly comprehensive answer. I'll see if Hoedown supports `markdown="1"` but I don't believe that it does. Switching Markdown implementations is *possible* but not in the timeframe for the particular thing I was trying to solve.

Comment: At least with the extensions I have enabled, not only does `markdown="1"` *not* make it actually process the markdown inside the `<div>`, but Hoedown still strips off the `markdown` pseudo-attribute, so I can't retroactively fix it up myself! Worst of both worlds, jeeze.